# Send keypress event to textarea js

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to automate somethings on some website

It has textarea and send btn (it all automatically generated with vue.js if it is matters, and this website is not mine)

`<textarea class="index_textarea_1O4S1 mb2"></textarea>`

`<btn disabled='disabled> <span>send </span> </btn>`

I need to set some text to textarea and press this button

But this code doesn't work

```
document.querySelector('textarea').textContent = "hello there"
document.querySelector('button').click()
```

As you can see btn stays disabled
[image]

I tried to remove disabled attribute of btn, but doesn't help also

So I guess the best option is to try to send keypress event to textarea
How do I do it?

BTW I don't know why but jquery $ functions seems to work strange from console on this website, so vanilla js is preferable

Comment: could you please let me know the answer for this question if you have done !! that will help me more

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand correctly,

When I have run into this problem in the past, it's because there is some event listener that I'm trying to trigger and the element I send the event to is either targeting the wrong event or the wrong element. You can use dev tools to try and isolate the desired event, and you can send an event by creating it manually instead of calling the `.click` method.

For example:

```js
const txtArea = document.querySelector('textarea');
txtArea.textContent = "hello there";
const inputEv = new Event("input", { bubbles: true });
const keydownEv = new Event("keydown", { bubbles: true });
const keyupEv = new Event("keyup", { bubbles: true });
txtArea.dispatchEvent(inputEv);
txtArea.dispatchEvent(keydownEv);
txtArea.dispatchEvent(keyupEv);
document.querySelector('button')
  .dispatchEvent(new Event("click", { bubbles: true });
```

creating the event this way lets you even trigger custom events, once identified, by changing the first argument passed to the new Event constructor, and triggers parent elements by setting the option bubbles to true.